# md-checkbox does not get set by ng-model value inside a directive's link() function

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm building a questionnaire out of directives which show the correct `input` based on certain expectations. Those expectations (including any formerly given input from the user) comes from a parent `$scope`. Everything is set up in the `link` function of AngularJS's directive definition object

Where things go wrong is when using `md-checkbox`: the `ng-model` of the checkbox inside the directive is set to `true`, the `md-checkbox` is still false. I can confirm that by adding a simple `input type="checkbox"` with the same `ng-model` property, the simple checkbox is checked, whereas the `md-checkbox` isn't.

Whenever I click on the `md-checkbox` twice, it does get checked. So I gather that there is something wrong with the binding. I built a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/lodybo/pen/pweMqe) which demonstrates it. The code inside the pen is almost taken verbatim from my source code

Stuff that I already tried:

- Using `$scope.$apply()` after handling all (DOM) logic in the `link` function
- Idem but with `$scope.$digest()`
- Setting a `$timeout` with no delay (as way of a 'safe' `$apply()`)
- Even going so far as to store the current answer (`true` or `false`) in a variable, setting the `ng-model` property to `undefined`, and then setting it back to the stored value, all inside a `$timeout`

I'm at loss here, it looks like something simple given the fact that all the other inputs have their correct data in it.

Comment: For me everything works fine

Comment: For me everything works fine too.

Comment: Really? So when the pen has loaded you see two checkboxes currently being checked? I only see one..

Comment: Replace class with ng-class

Comment: @Robin Yes, that was it!

Comment: Glad that it helped !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace class with ng-class because ng-class lets you to dynamically bind the class to the element

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your codepen the problem is `class="md-checkbox-{{expression}}"`. I forked your [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZRNoz). `You can use ng-class`. I think this is a bug.

Comment: Yes, correct. @Robin was a bit faster with the answer but I still upvoted yours for having tangible proof.